# Sqoop export to mysql very slow

Tags: sqoop

I am trying to export some data to mysql using SQOOP. Though I specify this parameter --num-mappers 12, it allocates only one mapper to work on this job. And, it is extremely slow. How do I make sure Sqoop job gets more mappers and not 1.

Answer (score 0):

The number of mappers is determined based upon these criteria

- Size of the file in HDFS
- Format of the file and whether it supports splittable
- Splittable and non-splittable if the file is compressed

Run this command `hadoop fs -du -s -h <path_of_the_file>` to get the size of the file. Also check parameter values min split size and max split size.